# How to commit working copy to CVS repository if some files are deleted from working copy?

Tags: cvs, commit

I want to commit my working copy to CVS repository, first I do:

```
>>> cvs -n update
```

to see what changes were made. I get the following:

```
cvs update: warning: crc/etable.tar.gz was lost
```

Then I try to commit:

```
>>> commit cvs

cvs commit: Up-to-date check failed for `crc/etable.tar.gz'
cvs [commit aborted]: correct above errors first!
```

I don't understand what I'm missing above. If a file is deleted from my working copy, why is it a problem? How do I solve this issue and commit to CVS repository?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to make the removal of the file permanent then you need to tell cvs. ie.

```
cvs rm crc/etable.tar.gz
```

Then commit as normal. If you do a `cvs update`, the file should show with status `R` meaning it is scheduled for removal.

If the file was removed accidentally and you actually want it back, you can retrieve it from the repository:

```
cvs up crc/etable.tar.gz
```